# how can I get expr:content value from meta tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how canI get  **expr:content**  value using JavaScript ??!!

```
<meta expr:content='data:blog.blogId' itemprop='blogId'/>
<meta expr:content='data:post.id' itemprop='postId'/>
```

i tryed the methode of getElementsByTagName("meta") 

`var x = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
txt=x.expr:content;`

but he give me **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `document.querySelectorAll()` with selector `"meta[expr\\:content]"` , `for` loop , `.getAttribute()`

```js
var metas = document.querySelectorAll("meta[expr\\:content]");

for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
  console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("expr:content"))
}
```

```html
<meta expr:content='data:blog.blogId' itemprop='blogId' />
<meta expr:content='data:post.id' itemprop='postId' />
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<span expr:content='data:blog.blogId' itemprop='blogId'/>
<span expr:content='data:post.id' itemprop='postIds'/>
</head>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var metas = document.querySelectorAll("meta[expr\\:content]");

for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
  txt=console.log(metas[i].getAttribute("expr:content"));
alert (txt); 
}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>`

I tried this code but he didn't give me any answer

Comment: @AymenLaroussi  _"tried this code but he didn't give me any answer"_ No `meta` elements appear at `html` at comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099978/how-can-i-get-exprcontent-value-from-meta-tag-using-javascript/34100075?noredirect=1#comment55964244_34100075 ? Why are `span` elements within `head` of document ? See original Question: _"how can I get expr:content value from meta tag using javascript"_

Comment: just want to have the `'data:blog.blogId'` value and `'data:post.id'` value using javascript  wish variable 
`x = 'data:blog.blogId' value`
`y =  'data:post.id' value`
using JavaScript to extract them

Comment: @AymenLaroussi Try declaring variables outside of `for` loop , checking `i` jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4vcdnmvg/ ; or filter by `itemprop`

Comment: please give me a favor i'm not pro i'm just beginner in coding
please if you want give me the hole solution i'm tired of testing
wanna copy past